# Does existence of orthonormal bases imply the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, axiom-of-choice, orthonormal

It's easy to see that by Zorn's Lemma, all Hilbert spaces admit an orthonormal basis, and furthermore two Hilbert spaces are isomorphic iff their orthonormal bases have the same cardinality.

I'm wondering if the reverse direction is true: Does the existence of orthonormal bases for all Hilbert spaces imply the Axiom of Choice?

I don't know how hard this problem is.